# Fetching csv data on Internet Explorer failed

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, d3.js, fetch-api

I just tried to fetch a CSV file using d3.js **v5**. Data fetching is working fine in all browsers except **Internet Explorer 10+**.

```
d3.csv("test.csv").then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
});
```

This is showing an error fetch is not defined in Internet Explorer.

I am using d3.v5.min.js.

Comment: Hi, you can use a lower version of d3, [4 is said to support IE9+](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki#supported-environments), or you can try adding a [pollyfill for fetch](https://github.com/github/fetch)

Comment: Or just stop supporting IE altogether it has such a low market share nowdays

Comment: @Endless I really wish you were correct... But you're not. There are still a lot of IE users today. According to some measurements (they differ) it's the third most used browser in 2019, with almost 7% market share.

Comment: according to [statcounter.com](http://gs.statcounter.com/browser-version-partially-combined-market-share/desktop/worldwide/#monthly-201804-201906) IE11 is on 4% worldwide, IE < 11 is not even on the map. also, safari seems to [beat IE](http://gs.statcounter.com/browser-market-share/desktop/worldwide/#monthly-201804-201906), pushing IE to 4th place with 5% global market share

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`d3.csv` (and all other D3 fetch methods, for that matter) uses the Fetch API internally. If you look at the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), in the *browser compatibility* table, you'll see that the Fetch API is not supported by Internet Explorer (any version, not only 10+, as you said in your question).

The solution, therefore, is using a polyfill for Fetch (and for promises as well, see the comments below). There are several options online.

As an advice, instead of sniffing the user agent, try to check if the browser supports Fetch. Probably the simplest way is using `window.fetch`. The following snippet will log a truthy value in most browsers, and a false one in IE (and in other browser that doesn't support Fetch, if it exists):

```js
console.log(window.fetch)
```

So, in your code, you do something like this:

```
if(!window.fetch){
    //load the polyfill here
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much !!!
I just loaded two js files 
1. https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/promise-polyfill@8/dist/polyfill.min.js,
2 .https://github.com/github/fetch/releases (fetch.umd.js)

I got an error  "promise not defined" when i used fetch.umd.js alone.
After adding polyfill.min.js it is fixed. Now it is working perfectly fine.

Comment: @Nj_Coder yes, indeed, I forgot to mention that. These are the files I normally use for IE: `"https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/promise-polyfill@7/dist/polyfill.min.js"` and `"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fetch/2.0.4/fetch.min.js"`. I really long for the day when IE will be just a curiosity about the past.